# С++ Как работает передача/возврат массивов, в чём разница между int[][] и int**?

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели, преобразование

Так не компилируется

```
class A {
private: int arr[10][10];
public: int** getArr() {return arr;}
}
```

Так собирается, но получаем ошибку во время исполнения(код 11 - попытка доступа к заблокированной памяти) https://ideone.com/Pq9gLn

```
class A {
private: int arr[10][10];
public: int** getArr() {return (int**)arr;}
}
...
A a;
int** arr = a.getArr();
cout << arr[0][0];
```

Почему так? Ведь по идее int** и int[][] одно и то же. В чём разница?

Comment: `int** и int[][] одно и то же` -- нет.

Comment: На самом деле разница есть. `int **` -- это адрес переменной, которая указывает на массив int (т.е. на `int []`), а вот `int [][]` с т.з. расположения в памяти -- это тот же `int []` (последовательность 32-разрядных слов в памяти). Так что, возвращайте `&arr[0][0]` как `int *`, а в вызывающем коде обращайтесь к матрице как к одномерному массиву `a[i][j] == a[i * N + j]` (где N это количество столбцов (т.е. элементов каждой строки) матрицы).

Comment: Можете почитать мою [статью](http://scrutator.me/post/2016/03/30/pointers_demystified_p3.aspx), я там детально разобрал отличия.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Массив в выражениях преобразуется к указателю на свой первый элемент.

Если у вас есть, например, объявление массива

```
T a[N];
```

где `T` это некоторый тип, а `N` - число элементов в массиве, то использование имени `a` в выражениях преобразуется к типу `T *`. Это можно представить как

```
T *tmp = a;
```

Двумерный массив - это массив массивов. То есть если у вас есть массив вида

```
int a[10][10];
```

то `a` - это массив из 10 элементов, которые в свою очередь массивы с типом `int[10]`.

Вы можете ввести объявление `typedef` для этих элементов.

Например,

```
typedef int T[10];
```

И тогда объявление массива будет выглядеть как

```
T a[10];
```

Как сказано выше, в выражениях массив преобразуется в указатель на свой первый элемент.

Следовательно это преобразование можно представить как

```
T *tmp = a;
```

где `T` - это алиас для типа `int[10]` Следовательно, если убрать объявление `typedef`, то вы получите

```
int ( *tmp )[10] = a;
```

Типы `int ( * )[10]` и `int **` - два разных типа.

Например, выведите на консоль размер объектов, для которых определены эти указатели и сравните их

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    int **p;
    int ( *q )[10];

    std::cout << sizeof( *p ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << sizeof( *q ) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы может выглядеть следующим образом

```
4
40
```

То есть в первом случае выводится размер скалярного объекта, а во втором случае размер массива.

Поэтому правильное определение метода в вашем классе будет выглядеть так

```
class A 
{
private: 
    int arr[10][10];

public: 
    int ( * getArr() )[10] { return arr; }
};
```

или

```
class A 
{
private: 
    int arr[10][10];

public: 
    typedef int ( *T )[10];
    T getArr() { return arr; }
};
```

Что касается вашего примера

```
class A {
private: int arr[10][10];
public: int** getArr() {return (int**)arr;}
}; 
...
A a;
int** arr = a.getArr();
cout << arr[0][0];
```

то переменная `arr` получит адрес экстента, занимаемого исходным двумерным массивом. При использовании выражения `arr[0]` происходит обращение к памяти массива, где хранится его первый элемент. При этом предполагается, что `arr[0]` , эквивалентное выражению `*arr`, в свою очередь вернет указатель. Но исходный массив не хранит указатели. Он хранит в общем случае произвольные значения. Поэтому происходит ошибка обращения к памяти.

Для наглядности рассмотрите следующий пример. Допустим, что `sizeof( int )` и `sizeof( int * )` равны между собой. Чтобы у вас работала конструкция `arr[0][0]`, где `arr` имеет тип `int **`, исъодный массив должен быть определен, как показано в следующей демонстрационной программе.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    int a[][2] = 
    {
        { reinterpret_cast<int>( &a[1][0] ), 20 },
        { 30, 40 },
    };

    int **arr =  reinterpret_cast<int **>( a );

    std::cout << arr[0][0] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

В этом случае `arr[0]` возвратит указатель на элемент массива `a[1][0]`, то есть `&a[1][0]` . Применяя к полученному выражению снова оператор индексирования, вы получите целое число `30`.

Однако если первый элемент массива содержит произвольное целое число, как, например, `10`, то  `arr[0]` вернет это значение, которое в выражении `arr[0][0]` будет интерпретироваться как адрес памяти, и произойдет ошибка обращения к памяти.

Таким образом указатель

```
int **arr;
```

интерпретирует массив

```
int a[N][N];
```

как массив, имеющий тип

```
int * tmp[N];
```

То есть рассматривает элементы исходного массива как объекты, хранящие действительные значения указателей, а это в общем случае не так.

Comment: Спасибо, Получается, `**p` - адрес на адрес, `(*q)[10]` - статический массив адресов на первые элементы. Значит по адресу `*q + 2` находится второй адрес, т.е. первый элемент массива номер 2. Тогда по идее `*(q + 2)`, должен вернуть этот элемент, НО если было выполнено приведение `(int**)q` и вернуть из функции, как в  примере вопроса, то не даёт обратиться к памяти - Вы не знаете в чём проблема?

Comment: @Nikita int( *q )[10] - это указатель на объект, который является массивом из 10 элементов. Поэтому, например, операция ++q изменит значение в q на величину 10 * sizeof( int ), и как следует из примера в ответе на 40 байтов.  Выражение *( q + 2 ) возвращает ссылку на третий элемент двумерного массива, то есть, образно говоря, на третью строку в двумерном массиве.

Comment: http://cpp.sh/7wv5w Первый вариант не компилируется, http://cpp.sh/7ahs второй с `typedef` работает. Добавьте пожалуйста к ответу.

Comment: @Nikita Это была опечатка по забывчивости.:)